# how to resolve multiple inheritance

Tags: java, android, multiple-inheritance, extends

I am working in android.and when I am creating new project than By default it extends the **ActionBarActivity**.now I want to extends other activity that is **List Activity** and it is predefined activity in android,but we know that java doesn't support **multiple inheritance**.
                         so how can i solve it because if i remove the **extends actionbaractivity** line from the program than it gives **fatal exception**. and if i use **actionbaractivty or listactivity as interface** than error comes that **these class are not super interface**.My main motive is to **extends listactivity**.

so please give me some solution.....

Comment: Just add a ListView to an ActionBarActivity. A ListActivity is just a regular Activity with a ListView and some convenience methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to link 
 [ActioBarActivity with ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524008/combining-listactivity-and-actionbaractivity)

ActionBarActivity is from AppCompat library. When you want support apps in older device then you should use ActionBarActivity.You can use ListFragment with ActionBarActivity

Comment: i donot need action bar for my project,i want only listactivity but when i am creating new project than by default it extends actionbaractiivty.

Comment: @rajeevtejapuriya you can have a listview in your activity. that is what Mike suggested

Comment: @rajeevtejapuriya Your activity  extends ActionBarActivity because android create project with older version support i.e. support library (appcompat v7) is used.So As Mike suggested you can applied

Comment: You can see this link http://androidexample.com/Create_Listview_With_ListActivity_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=66&aaid=91 for listActivity