# nullPointerException when accessing ActionBar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I'm getting a nullPointerException when I try to access my `ActionBar`

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

my recipientsActivity is this

```
package com.ahmetyuva.ribbit;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.List;


public class RecipientsActivity extends ListActivity{

    public static final String TAG = RecipientsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected List<ParseUser> mFriends;
    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;

    protected MenuItem mSendMenuItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipients);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = mFriendsRelation.getQuery();
        query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {

                if(e == null) {

                    mFriends = friends;

                    String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                        usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                        i++;

                    }                   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getListView().getContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                            usernames);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else{

                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecipientsActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipients, menu);
        mSendMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:

                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_send:
                return true;
        }
      /*  int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
*/
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        if (l.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {
            mSendMenuItem.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            mSendMenuItem.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

my error log is here

```
04-13 11:19:05.148 1956-1956/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ahmetyuva.ribbit/com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.RecipientsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.RecipientsActivity.onCreate(RecipientsActivity.java:40) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

menu_recipients xml is here

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.RecipientsActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_send"
          android:title="Send"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          android:visible="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
        />


</menu>
```

activity_recipients xml is here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.RecipientsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_recipients_list_message"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".RibbitApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_friends"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

<!--                   IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".RecipientsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipients"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ahmetyuva.ribbit.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You are extending ListActivity. You need to extend ActionBarActivity.

Comment: but then my list activity properties are not working if i extend actionbaractivity.

Comment: You could just import the listView using another id instead, and then do whatever you want on your listView.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
getSupportedActionBar() instead of getActionBar()
```

Comment: I think it is that except it is getSupportActionBar() not getSupportedActionBar() :)

Comment: He is sub-classing android.app.ListActivity, is getSupportActionBar() actually available? see [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), and its inherited classes.

Comment: getSupportActionBar() is not available

Comment: Use this

      public class RecipientsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

 }
}


its working...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you actually have an `ActionBar`, if for example, your theme is:
`Theme.Light.NoActionBar`, you won't have an action bar.
So, make sure your `theme` has and `Actionbar`

EDIT:

Try with the following theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

If that doesn't work, You should consider changing to fragments, as suggested in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528156/3753786)

Comment: i have this <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. it gives this error it did not even loaded

Comment: i think problem is not about theme, getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); i have this error

Comment: I have edited it again, please try the new theme suggestion. If that doesn't work, check the link I provided,

Comment: Ok, then you should consider changing to fragments, check the link I provided

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always do this to avoid this kind of error :

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
if (ab == null) {
    Log.d("test", "ab null");
}
else {
    Log.d("test", "ab not null");
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Then, what is in the logcat with the tag "test" ?

Comment: getSupportActionBar i dont have this method.

Answer (score 0):

For both activities,
in your onCreate the next line after setContentView( ... )
add the following :

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in the manifest for both activities add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

in the tag directly after

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```