# getActionBar() throwing Null pointer error

Tags: java, android, material-design

i am getting Null pointer Error while using this.

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in my java class which extends ListActivity
After upgraded my theme to Theme.AppCompat i am getting this error.
I checked all solution given on stackoverflow but nothing help me.

MainActivity

```
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
     ......


     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        {
          .....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
           final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the two
            // primary sections of the app.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
            // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
            // a reference to the Tab.
            mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                //if a tab was changed by a swipe gesture
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position); //update the tab bar to match the selected page
                    mDisplayedFragIndex=position;   //update the index of the currently displayed frag
                    if (position==1)  //if the view has moved to the history fragment:
                    {
                        mHistoryFrag.loadHistory(); //reload the history list view
                    }
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            });

            ActionBar.TabListener tabListener=new ActionBar.TabListener(){
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

                }


            };


            // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
            for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++)
            {
                // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
                // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
                // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
                // this tab is selected.
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
            }//for
    .....
    }
```

Here is xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    />
```

I am using viewpager here how should i do i still getting error while declaring toolbar xml in activity_main.xml and code in main activity.

Activity2  //**In this activity i getting error.**
....

```
public class Activity2 extends ListActivity
    {

    .....
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
            setupActionBar();
        }
         private void setupActionBar()
         {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
          {
           // enables the activity icon as a 'home' button. required if "android:targetSdkVersion" > 14

           getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
           getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
          }
         }

    }
```

Activity2 extends ListFragment

```
public class Activity2 extends ListFragment
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat,
                container, false);
        setupActionBar();
        return view;
    }
    private void setupActionBar()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            // enables the activity icon as a 'home' button. required if "android:targetSdkVersion" > 14
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); **//Getting Error in this line "Cannot Resolved "**
            //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}//end of class
```

Comment: Post full *code* with *extends class*.

Comment: updated my ques

Comment: Change `Activity2` class to *extends* *ActionBarActivity*.

Comment: @jaydroider firstofall ActionBarActivity is deprected and second thing i am not able to use "getListView()" after extending this

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious.

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Extends from `AppCompatActivity` and there is no problem with that because:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Has `getSupportActionBar()`.But, You are using `getActionBar()` in the `Activity2` which extends from `ListActivity` and as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528156/4409113) says;

> **`ListActivity` hasn't been ported to `AppCompat`**. Probably ***because you should consider it 'deprecated', and instead use a ListFragment***.

Comment: So i am updating from listactiviy to listfragment i got lots of error still i am able to resolve many but again i am getting error in "getSupportActionBar()" not resolved

Comment: Please update your question with new Activity codes & logcat.

Comment: I have written simple code(Updated my question) still getting error in "getSupportActionBar", even i am not able to use getActionBar()

Comment: @MukeshGupta - I think you didn't get the point, You should get the `Toolbar`(in this case) In the main `Activity`, Please read this doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html - Which says; `A fragment that displays a list of items by binding to a data source such as an array or Cursor, and exposes event handlers when the user selects an item.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

**UPDATE**

You will first need a toolbar-

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);// define in activity
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: yes i tried it says "Cannot resolve method getSupportActionBar()"

Comment: ListActivity is not an AppCompatActivity, that's why you can't use getSupportActionBar(). This is perhaps useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524008/combining-listactivity-and-actionbaractivity